# How to set/change properties (userMetadata, fileName, creation time etc. ) of an uploaded blob stored in google cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

After uploading a blob from the url generated by

```
blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(path, UploadOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageBucketName("xyz"))
```

How can we set/change properties on it? like userMetadata, fileName, creation time etc.

If it is not possible, is there a workaround to attach custom information for uploaded blobs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cloud Storage library to set metadata/ACL (it's a different API to the same storage). See example here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted#writing_an_object_to_a_gcs_file - the second argument is used to set metadata/ACL.

Comment: That is the alternative we used. But it does not directly answer the the question.